# another relative layout centering issue

Tags: android, layout, center, android-relativelayout, centering

I have a problem centering a OK button at the end of a Relative layout, i've checked a lot of similar questions, but couldn't find my mistake. whatever i try, the OK button is still offset from the center.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag_choix_surface"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNbPieces"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pieces"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSurface"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChmin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="min :" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/nb_piece_min"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChmax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="max :" >

    </TextView>

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/nb_piece_max"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOkNbPieces"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pieces"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="OK" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sorry i couldn't include a screenshot, i'm fresh new to the site, and don't have any rep!
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `RelativeLayout` you have to use `android:layout_centerHorizontal`, `android:layout_centerVertical` or `android:layout_centerInParent` attributes.

Change the button part of the xml to:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOkNbPieces"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pieces"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="OK" />
```

And remove attributes `android:gravity`, `android:layout_marginLeft` and `android:layout_marginRight` from the parent `RelativeLayout`, these attributes affects the center position of the inner items. So the `RelativeLayout` should be defined like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/frag_choix_surface"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer, i tried it allready , and just rechecked it. but the button still doesn't move to center...

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope i answered your question.

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/frag_choix_surface"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewNbPieces"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pieces"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSurface"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChmin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="min :" />

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/nb_piece_min"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChmax"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="max :" >

    </TextView>

    <kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView android:id="@+id/nb_piece_max"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:layout_marginLeft="111dp"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pieces"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the button is indeed center, but not the linearlayout anymore (offset on the left)...

Comment: Easy fix, just add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to the `LinearLayout`. And you will probably need to update the margins of the inner `TextViews` too.